# Использование класса на c++ из java для андроида

Tags: jni, c, java, android, c++

Поделитесь проектом для андроида с использованием `jni`, в котором можно посмотреть, как из `java` вызывается класс написанный на `c++`. Я в этом вопросе довольно сильно туплю и попытки понять, как это делается отлично проваливаются.  
Пишу `xml` парсер с использованием `sax`, который можно дергать из `java`.

Answer (score 5):

Вот, пожалуйста: [Как написать программу на `C++` для `Android`. Используем С++ класс и `STL`](http://jia3ep.blogspot.com/2011/11/c-android-3-stl.html)

Comment: Хорошая ссылка.

Answer (score 1):

Еще один простой пример: [Работаем с кодом `C/C++` на `Android`: основы `Android NDK` и `Java Native Interface`](http://idev.by/android/21115/)